# Через composer поставил chat, как правильно удалить его с проекта?

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Поставил себе через composer [чат](https://github.com/sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte)

Смотрю в классе не все методы, как его теперь правильно удалить и по новой установить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удали строку с названием пакета(sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte) в composer.json и набери команду composer update

или `composer remove sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte`